# Facebook like box showing only a few faces

Tags: wordpress, facebook-likebox

it works perfectly on Safari but in every browser it shows just 3 pages. I had changed the page title including which changed the url so that might be it. I don't know a way around it. The code I pasted is

Website I am trying to use it for is http://reviews.realtvchat.com/

Comment: What does your source look like to call this like box?

Comment: You mean the code?  <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FRealTVChat&width=292&height=500&colorscheme=dark&show_faces=true&border_color=%23520610&stream=false&header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:500px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: Try changing to the HTML5 or XFBML version of the like box code. The IFRAME code is not optimal.

Comment: I tried to put the  HTML5 or XFBML codes in a text edit widget for the sidebar. Didn't work either

Comment: You should file a bug report with Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks for the link cpliko but they don't have an option to file a report.

Comment: It's there. You've got to type something in the search box first.